# My jquery code dosen't seem to be sending data to php, How can we send data to php using jQuery, and how does php receive it?

Tags: php, jquery

I have tried using the jQuery post function, but it isn't working, php is not picking up and data, I need this to validate whether or not the user has logged in or not into the app, so we need to send a boolean which tells php if the user is logged in or not, then php will send proper information back to the client, if they are already logged.

```
This is the jQuery function that I'm using

function check_items(){

let info=[localStorage.getItem("username"),localStorage.getItem("uuid"),localStorage.getItem("school_id")];
if(!info[0]||!info[1]||!info[2]){

    let Register="register=false";
    $.post("Signup.php",Register,function(){

    },"json");

}


}

This is the Signup.php file



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Cheater.com</title>
<link href="Signup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="Signup.js"></script>
<script src="../JQuery/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body >


 <?php 

   class Set_Signup{

function __construct(){
    echo " <section id='background'>
    <h1 id='title'>Cheater</h1>
    <hr>
</section>

  

    <section id='main' >

        <form action='../Login/index.php' method='POST' id='signup' onsubmit='check_items()' >
            <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='username' class='username' /><br>
            <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='password' class='password'/><br>
            <input type='text' name='school' placeholder='School Name' class='school' /><br>
            <input type='submit' value='Enter' class='enter'/>
        </form>

    </section>
";
}
```

}

```
class operations{
    function __construct(){}

    function recieve_register(){
        return $_POST['register'];
    }

    function handle_user(){

        if($this->recieve_register()===false){
           //do nothing as javascript will redirect the user to landing.php
        }else{
            $signup= new Set_Signup();
            echo $_POST['register']; 
        }

    }

   
}


$opp= new operations();
$opp->handle_user();
```

?>

Comment: There are tons of tutorials on the internet. Please ask for specific problem.

Comment: Do you recommend any specific tutorial for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a simple way to send an ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {"key":"value"},
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

and in the PHP code that returns the ajax result:

```
<?php
   var_dump($_POST);
   die();
?>
```